# All the Appear Month and Week count from start to end date in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, dateformatter

I am trying to get the months and week count from start date to end date but its (Below code) counting the number of days and accordingly return the month and week count. But need to show the data month and week wise on graph. How can I achieve this, like for below two given dates I am expecting the month count 4 but getting 2 and week count 1 but expecting 3. Please help to find this thanks in advance.

For Month I used this code

```
    let fromStr = "2020-11-25 08:00:00 +0000"
    let toStr = "2021-2-10 08:00:00 +0000"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"
    let fromDate = dateFormatter.date(from: fromStr) ?? Date()
    let toDate = dateFormatter.date(from: toStr) ?? Date()
    var count = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: fromDate, to: toDate).month
```

I am getting count value 2
but I need value 4

For Week I used this code :

```
    let fromStr = "2021-1-25 08:00:00 +0000"
    let toStr = "2021-2-3 08:00:00 +0000"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZ"
    let fromDate = dateFormatter.date(from: fromStr) ?? Date()
    let toDate = dateFormatter.date(from: toStr) ?? Date()
    var count = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekOfMonth], from: fromDate, to: toDate).weekOfMonth ?? 0
```

getting week count 1
But need value 3

Comment: I got `3` as the output. It seems like you can just add 1 to `count` to get the desired output, since you are including both the starting month and ending month in the count.

Comment: I tested, and I got 3. It should be 3 months and 1 day, no? What are your values for `fromDate` & `toDate`? So are you expecting to get 4 rounding up?

Comment: oops,I update in my code please try now

Comment: I still don't understand why you should get value 4: `11-25 to 12-25`(1); `12-25 to 01-25`(2), `01-25 to 02-25` (3); but since you go only up to 02-03, it's less than 3.

Comment: You seem to counting one more month than what people usually count. If you really want, you could just add 1 to the solution shown in my answer in the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Larme. I need to show the data on graph by month and week wise. In above code we are hitting the four months data but I am getting just 2 months, that's why I need 4 value.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper But its not the feasible solution.

Comment: I see why you want this now. In that case the duplicate is suitable. Just add 1 to the result that solution gives.

Comment: @Sweeper its not the duplicate one. I mentioned about week also and your answer is not to calculate week count between two dates. Also I am updating the question.